# Problems with functions 3

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a problem, I have a `view` in the database that makes a`group BY`, and have another table `GraficoCor`, I make every time the`While` the first function makes an increment he pass the counter value for the variable `IdCor` the second function, the second function will query having as reference the value of`IdCor` returning to color in hex for the first function.
How to do that?

Function GetFaturamentoIVEL

```
public static FatoFaturamentoIVELBO[] GetFaturamentoIVEL(string Operacao, Connection Cn)
        {            
            var RsFaturamento = new Recordset();
            int Cont = 0;
            try
            {
                RsFaturamento.Open(String.Format("SELECT Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing, SUM(ValorNF)AS ValorTotal FROM dbo.FatoFaturamentoIVEL WHERE TradeMarketing = 0  and AnoMes = '2016/04' GROUP BY Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing ORDER BY SUM(ValorNF) ASC", Operacao), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                var ArrayRetorno = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO[RsFaturamento.RecordCount];
                while (!RsFaturamento.EOF)
                {
                    FatoFaturamentoIVELBO Faturamento = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO();
                    Faturamento.Operacao = RsFaturamento.Fields["Operacao"].Value.ToString();
                    Faturamento.AnoMes = RsFaturamento.Fields["AnoMes"].Value.ToString();
                    Faturamento.ValorNF = decimal.Parse(RsFaturamento.Fields["ValorTotal"].Value.ToString());
                    ArrayRetorno[Cont] = Faturamento;    
                    Cont++;
                    RsFaturamento.MoveNext();
                }
                RsFaturamento.Close();
                return ArrayRetorno;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Function GetCor

```
public  static FatoFaturamentoIVELBO GetCor(int IdCor, Connection Cn)
        {
            var Cor = new FatoFaturamentoIVELBO();
            var RsCor = new Recordset();
            try
            {
                RsCor.Open(String.Format("SELECT IdCor, CodHex from dbo.GraficoCor  where IdCor = " + IdCor), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
                if (!RsCor.EOF)
                {
                    Cor.CodHex = RsCor.Fields["CodHex"].Value.ToString();
                }
                return Cor;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Comment: Which part isn't working, or which part do you not know how to implement?

Comment: @Bmm6o Hello, I do not know how to implement.

Comment: What is it that you don't know how to implement? You see the problem here is that you need help but you have not explained what you are trying to do or what you need help with. As of now you have not asked a complete question, just a vague bit of code with no basis on anything concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you just call something like:

```
Faturamento.SomeProperty = GetCor(Cont, Cn)
```

This is unlikely to be what you want for two reasons.  It's usually a mistake to use a counter like that to produce database ids, instead the id should be returned as part of the query.  And instead of making a separate request for each row, you should join the queries together and get the data all at once.  See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you primarily speak another language - that's fine and not your fault - but it's really hard to understand what you're asking.  Could you edit what you wrote and word it differently?

This is a total guess, but I think you need to rewrite your first query:

`SELECT Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing, SUM(ValorNF)AS ValorTotal FROM dbo.FatoFaturamentoIVEL WHERE TradeMarketing = 0  and AnoMes = '2016/04' GROUP BY Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing ORDER BY SUM(ValorNF) ASC`

So that it uses an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the `dbo.GraficoCor` so that you don't have to call `GetCor` each time through your `while` loop.

---

I think you could either do a sub-select or something like this should show you how to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT 
[Person Name], 
[Row Type]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Person Name] ASC) AS [Id]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'Alice' [Person Name] UNION
        SELECT 'Bob' [Person Name] UNION
        SELECT 'Charlie' [Person Name]  UNION
        SELECT 'Daniel' [Person Name] 
    ) [Alias]
) AS [Main]

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT 0 [Parity], 'Even Row' [Row Type] UNION
    SELECT 1 [Parity], 'Odd Row' [Row Type]
) [Lookup]
ON [Main].[Id] % 2 = [Lookup].[Parity]
```

Results:

```
Person Name | Row Type
----------------------
Alice       | Odd Row
Bob         | Even Row
Charlie     | Odd Row
Daniel      | Even Row
```

---

So in your case inside your `GetFaturamentoIVEL` function you can do this (untested):

```
RsFaturamento.Open(String.Format("@
SELECT 
[OrderedQuery].[Operacao], 
[OrderedQuery].[AnoMes], 
[OrderedQuery].[TradeMarketing],
[OrderedQuery].[ValorTotal],
[GraficoCor].[CodHex]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(ValorNF) ASC)) - 1 AS [IdCor]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        Operacao, 
        AnoMes, 
        TradeMarketing,
        SUM(ValorNF) AS ValorTotal 
        FROM dbo.FatoFaturamentoIVEL 
        WHERE TradeMarketing = 0 and AnoMes = '2016/04' 
        GROUP BY Operacao, AnoMes, TradeMarketing           
    ) [Query]
) AS [OrderedQuery]    
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GraficoCor] [GraficoCor] ON [OrderedQuery].[IdCor] = [GraficoCor].[IdCor]
", Operacao), Cn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly);
```